# Is it possible to ignore Incorrect Tag Value in Quickfix

Tags: quickfix, fix-protocol

We have integration with multiple vendors and sometime vendor add a new enum value in existing field. Qucikfix will reject the message if field value in not defined in data dictionary. Is it possible to ignore that field if value is not defined. I know there is field **ValidateUserDefinedFields=N** but that works if field not defined in data dictionary. If field has pre defined enum values then quickfix is still rejecting the message if field value is not defined in dictionry.

Thanks

Comment: Why do you want to ignore it ? Why don't you agree with your counterparty on what values are to be expected ?

Answer (score 1):

You could use `AllowUnknownMsgFields=Y` (https://www.quickfixj.org/usermanual/1.6.1/usage/configuration.html). If that does not help, you may want to not validate the messages at all (`ValidateIncomingMessage=N`).

Answer (score 0):

Yes that is best case scenario. Sometime counterparty will make a change without informing us that create this issue. To fix we have to update data dictionary in production. It will be great if we can ignore that tag if enum value is missing in data dictionary as most of time that tag is custom and not relevant to us.